# Groovy script to execute multiple different job on jenkins without using pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have to create job that executes multiple job on jenkins. this has to be done without using pipeline.

Comment: Please be clear in what you are asking. Share what your requirement is along with what the use case is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin 
You can set it to post/build actions.